# Matlab fscanf read two column character/hex data from text file

Tags: matlab

Need to read in data stored as two columns of hex values in text file temp.dat into a Matlab variable with 8 rows and two columns.

Would like to stick with the fcsanf method.

temp.dat looks like this (8 rows, two columns):

```
0000 7FFF
30FB 7641
5A82 5A82
7641 30FB
7FFF 0000
7641 CF05
5A82 A57E
30FB 89BF

% Matlab code
fpath = './';
fname = 'temp.dat';
fid = fopen([fpath fname],'r');
% Matlab treats hex a a character string
formatSpec = '%s %s';
% Want the output variable to be 8 rows two columns
sizeA = [8,2];
A = fscanf(fid,formatSpec,sizeA)
fclose(fid);
```

Matlab is producing the following which I don't expect.

A = 8×8 char array

```
'03577753'
'00A6F6A0'
'0F84F48F'
'0B21F12B'
'77530CA8'
'F6A00F59'
'F48F007B'
'F12B05EF'
```

In another variation, I attemped changing the format string like this

```
formatSpec = '%4c %4c';
```

Which produced this output:

A =

8×10 char array

```
'0↵45 F7↵78'
'031A3F65E9'
'00↵80 4A↵B'
'0F52F0183F'
'7BA7B0C20 '
'F 86↵0F F '
'F724700AB '
'F6 1F↵55  '
```

Still another variation like this:

```
formatSpec = '%4c %4c';
sizeA = [8,16];
A = fscanf(fid,formatSpec);
```

Produces a one by 76 character array:

A =

```
'00007FFF
 30FB 7641
 5A82 5A827641 30FB
 7FFF 0000
 7641CF05
 5A82 A57E
 30FB 89BF'
```

Would like and expect Matlab to produce a workspace variable with 8 rows and 2 columns.

Have followed the example on the Matlab help area here:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html

My Matlab code is based on the 'read file contents into an array' section about 1/3 of the way down the page.  The example I reference is doing something very similar except that the two columns are one int and one float rather than two characters.

Running Matlab R2017a on Redhat.

Here is the complete code with the solution provided by Azim and comments about
what I learned as a result of posting the question.

```
fpath = './';
fname = 'temp.dat';
fid = fopen([fpath fname],'r');
formatSpec = '%9c\n';
% specify the output size as the input transposed, NOT the input.
sizeA = [9,8];
A = fscanf(fid,formatSpec,sizeA);
% A' is an 8 by 9 character array, which is the goal matrix size.
% B is an 8 by 1 cell array, each member has this format 'dead beef'.
%
% Cell arrays are data types with indexed data containers called cells, 
%  where each cell can contain any type of data.
B = cellstr(A');
% split divides str at whitespace characters.
S = split(C)
fclose(fid)
```

S =

8×2 cell array

```
'0000'    '7FFF'
'30FB'    '7641'
'5A82'    '5A82'
'7641'    '30FB'
'7FFF'    '0000'
'7641'    'CF05'
'5A82'    'A57E'
'30FB'    '89BF'
```

Comment: My guess is you need `%4c` instead of `%s`, reading the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely your, 8x2 MATLAB variable would end up being a cell array. This can be done in two steps.

First, your lines have 9 characters so you could use `formatSpec = '%9c\n'` to read each line. Next you need to adjust the size parameter to read 9 rows and 8 columns; `sizeA = [9 8]`. This will read in all 9 characters into columns of the output; transposing the output will get you closer.

In the second step you need to convert the result of `fscanf` into your 8x2 cell array. Since you have R2017a you can then use [`cellstr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html) and [`split`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/split.html) to get your result.

Finally, if you need the integer values of each hex value you can use [`hex2dec`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hex2dec.html) on each cell in the cell-array.